# How can we add the Hyperlinks to azure boards work items?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, devops, azure-boards

How can we add the  Hyperlinks to azure boards work items ?

I want to add hyperlink to work items so that user can open work items and check the links.

Can we add new fields option for this hyperlink

Answer (score 0):

Just open `Links` tab, then `Add link->Existing item` and select `Hyperlink` link type:

[image]

And you can add it to the description:

[image]